# Links within `monospace` blocks

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, markdown, code-formatting

I frequently format function / variable names as monospace blocks for easier reading, but at the same time I often want to create hyperlinks of them to the relevant documentation. However, you can't do both.

Examples:

- `monospace only`
- [hyperlink only](http://www.example.com)
- `[monospace hyperlink](http://www.example.com)`

I'd like the last one to work, but as you can see it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can (do both):

[`monospace hyperlink`](http://www.example.com)

Code:

```
[`monospace hyperlink`](http://www.example.com)
```

You just have to put backticks **inside** the square bracket links.

Comment: Awesome! Now why didn't I think of that? Thanks!